# Man begins work in the Amazon forest as a logger, changes his mind after hallucinating with the locals

Tags: story-identification, movie

A man begins his new job cutting down trees in the Amazon forest. The locals are exploited in various ways, one of the females works as a prostitute.
Something happens with the man, I believe he meditates with a local shaman (it's possible that he takes some drugs) and hallucinates. In his vision he meets his spirit animal, which is a hawk. As he flies over the forest he sees the damage that is being done and completely changes his mind about his job.

I saw this movie as a little kid, it was a bit too much for me at the time but some scenes stayed with me for all these years. The movie is most likely from the 90s, first half.

Comment: Kind of cartoon FernGully: The Last Rainforest?

Comment: Sorry, it's not a cartoon.

Comment: What I ment is a similar plot

Comment: is this related to science fiction / fantasy in any way? Hallucination via a real world drug shouldn't really count right?

Comment: Avatar??  It must be

Comment: I'm quite certain now that it isn't the story you're looking for, but a Sci Fi classic you might  consider reading (in the same vein) is Alien Earth. It takes place in SE Asia (I think) and the logger ends up taking a sacred drug that slows his metabolism down to the rate of a tree's, and allows him to see the plant world's movement and decision making in real time. (Golden Age of Science Fiction, edited by Isaac Asimov)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the suggestion. I've been planning on reading a book by I Asimov.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on a few points here I think this might be a slightly confused recollection of [*The Emerald Forest*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089087/) (1985).

The major differences are:

- the American is a construction engineer building a dam, not a logger; though the construction does destroy a large piece of the jungle.
- the eagle is the spirit animal of his missing son (Tomme); when he dreams it is of a leopard, though he does see an image of the jungle being destroyed by a bulldozer

The story is about both the engineer and his son, who was kidnapped years before as a child.  A dozen years later the engineer goes back, the dam now nearly completed, to look for his son.

The son, meanwhile, has grown to adulthood among the Invisible People.  The father, looking for him, falls into the hands of their enemies the Fierce People and bargains his escape, but the result is the Fierce People buy guns.

The Fierce People raid the Invisible People, burning their village and selling the young women to a brothel.  Coming back to the village after his son's marriage (to one of the Invisible People), they team up to strike back at the Fierce People and free the women from the brothel.

The end of the movie is the father accepting that the dam must be destroyed, but also accepting that the jungle can take care of it without his help.

You can (at least for now) watch the movie on YouTube:

The son's vision takes place at 0:32; the father's vision takes place around 1:10.

The eagle re-appears to lead Tomme to his father for help rescuing the women at 1:30, and the attack on the brothel is at 1:35.  Tomme summons the eagle spirit at 1:42 to help bring down the dam.

Comment: this is it, thank you!

Answer (score 14):

Another possibility for a film with similar themes is "The Emerald Forest" (1985).  Wikipedia gives a detailed [plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emerald_Forest).

The protagonist is not a lumberjack, but he does have a job (engineer building a hydroelectric dam) that will involve the destruction of many trees in the rain forest.  At the end of the movie he does conclude that he was wrong, and he sabotages his own dam so that it bursts before the lake fills.

The "Something happens with the man" plot is that his son is taken by a local tribe who raise him as their own.  A decade later he meets his son again, now a tribe member and wants to help him.

There is also a spirit quest scene involving hallucinogens, but it does not feature the main character but rather his son.  So it could be a garbled memory.  There is also an extensive subplot with women from the tribe being rescued by force from a brothel.

Since the film was made in 1985, it is quite possible that you saw it in early 1990s.

It is not a perfect match.  But it has several points of similarity.  I think it is possible that it could be the film that you are remembering.

Answer (score 8):

This reminds me a bit of the early part of *Altered States* (1980, likely found on cable by 1990) starring William Hurt and Blair Brown.  He played an anthropologist, as I recall, but started out the movie studying Amazonian natives, documenting their rituals by participation.

The movie gets weirder later (I'm studying for my Masters in understatement), with one pivotal scene involving Hurt's character transforming into a misshapen glowing thing that looked to my eye like a lava man.  Surely would have been "too much" for a child...

Comment: I've just watched the trailer for this movie. Luckily it's not the right one, it looks quite disturbing (for a kid).